# How can I create a cookie for SurveyMonkney Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have an already generated popup survey Javascript code that shows my survey. How can I create a cookie so that it only pops up `30 seconds` after the user in on the website, and only fires once every `30 days`?

Here is my script file:

```js
(function(t, e, n, o) {
  var s, c, a;
  t.SMCX = t.SMCX || [], e.getElementById(o) || (s = e.getElementsByTagName(n), c = s[s.length - 1], a = e.createElement(n), a.type = "text/javascript", a.async = !0, a.id = o, a.src = ["https:" === location.protocol ? "https://" : "http://", "widget.surveymonkey.com/collect/website/js/AhN7nUpZa9_2F3gC6vSJkN3VsWkmDw6Oj7PaJqgjpmRLRGE8ot_2F8YzI1OnVSkE7Fll.js"].join(""), c.parentNode.insertBefore(a, c))
})(window, document, "script", "smcx-sdk");
```

Any advice will help! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your function works fine, you could try this:

1) On page load, check for your own cookie (which you will set to expire in 30 days whenever you create it.)

2) If you find a cookie, you're done. The user has seen your survey in the last 30 days.

3) If there is no cookie, wait 30 seconds, set a cookie to expire in 30 days, and show the survey.

```
<script>
function showSurvey() {
    console.log('About to show survey...');
    // put your survey popup function here
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        };
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    };
    return "";
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function checkCookie() {
    var cookieToCheck = getCookie("myCookie");
    if (cookieToCheck !== "") {
        console.log('Do nothing; user has cookie.');
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {                 // do this after 30 seconds
          setCookie("myCookie", "foo", 30);     // set your cookie
          showSurvey();
        }, 30000);
    }
}

checkCookie();  // check the cookie on page load
</script>
```

Note that if the user reloads the page, they are going to kill your setTimeout(). If you need to deal with page reloads, you'll need a server-side session or another cookie to track the time that the user has been on the site. You'll then decide on the server if the user should see the survey. Without more understanding of your environment, this simple client-side solution is all I can suggest for you.